# Block specific friend commenting on my other friend's posts

Tags: facebook

Can I prevent a friend from being able to comment on my other friend's posts on Facebook?

I have a friend that just doesn't get the general social rules of life. He keeps commenting on post from my other friend, people he doesn't know. He can see them if I have commented on them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can restrict your crazy-friend from commenting on your other friend's posts. But what you can do is,

1. Try teaching him 'general social rules of life' and tell him not to comment,
2. Tell your other friend to make their posts visible for `friends` only and not `public` / `friend-of-friends`. This way your crazy-friend can't see your friend's posts.
3. Extreme step - Tell your other friend to BLOCK your crazy-friend! This way your crazy-friend won't see your friend's profile/photos/status/comment ever! and you on the other hand can still be friends with both.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Do you have an authorative source for "There is no way you can restrict your crazy-friend from commenting on your other friend's posts"?

Answer (score 0):

"Remember, when you post to another person's timeline, [that person controls](http://www.facebook.com/help/www/120939471321735?rdrhc) what audience can view the post. Additionally, anyone who gets tagged in a post may see it, along with their friends."

"[Anyone](http://www.facebook.com/help/www/167598583302066?sr=1&sid=0iEjC1QkYX5NEqGIq) who can see a post can like or comment on it."

Sadly, as Rao mentioned, all your friends would have to change their settings to share with **friends**.  If they choose to allow sharing with **friends of friends**, I think you're out of luck.